# size readjustment of a txt file in Latex

Tags: fontsize

I am using the commands

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
    \VerbatimInput{file.txt}
\end{document}
```

and I can see my txt in LaTeX pdf. My problem is that the size of txt is bigger than latex pages form and it cut my words. How can I resize the txt so it fits the LaTeX pages font? Or another way to insert my txt file?

After i tried Phelype Oleinik suggestion:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting[breaklines]{file.txt}
\end{document}
```

It did allign it but some values went in wrong place, like this 
[image]

with my code it displayed the following:
[image]

It really meesed the data location. Is there an way to make the text smaller so it adjust in the latex font?

Comment: Maybe you could break `Maximum_Value` in two lines, so that the columns are narrower. I think it would look better :)

Comment: Do you really need to print a horrible table, when it's easy to make it beautiful?

Answer (score 1):

One option is, if you can switch to the `listings` package, to use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
  \lstinputlisting[breaklines]{file.txt}
\end{document}
```

then lines longer than the available text width will be broken.

---

#### Edit:

But if you want an *actual* table, then:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Descriptive Statistics}
  \begin{tabular}{*{6}{S[table-format=3.4]}}
    \toprule
    {Maximum} & {Minimum} & {Average} & {Median} & {Standard}  & {Variance}\\
    {Value}   & {Value}   & {Value}   & {Value}  & {Deviation} & \\
    \midrule
    115.9 & 72.5 & 95.426 &   95.9 & 15.044 & 226.31\\
       21 &    1 & 7.4615 &      7 & 5.8824 & 34.603\\
       71 &   26 & 48.154 &     52 & 15.561 & 242.14\\
       23 &    4 & 11.769 &      9 & 6.4051 & 41.026\\
       60 &    6 &     30 &     26 & 16.783 & 16.738\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried it, and it actually did it. But some values went in wrong places. It did not allign them correctly

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean. Can you show me a sample of the `file.txt` that produces this behavior you said?

Comment: I edited my question and added how my txt was displayed with my code

Comment: @NickosRaven Maybe you could use `\lstinputlisting[breaklines,basicstyle=\scriptsize]{file.txt}` to make the font size `\scriptsize` (or other that makes the table fit). But I must ask: do you _really_ need this table input verbatim? It looks odd to me...

Comment: Νο, it doesn't. It's my first time using Latex and it wasthe first thing i found that displayed my txt. That's why i said "Or another way to insert my txt file?". If you have another suggestion, i'm happy to hear it.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't need to be verbatim, try this: https://pastebin.com/G9SY8uuZ

Answer (score 0):

The file is just input at the current font size so you can use any latex font size command eg

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
    \footnotesize
    \VerbatimInput{file.txt}
\end{document}
```